# can no methods be declared in the main method?

Tags: java

I wrote this class (to print the array list) and in it I made a method in the `main` function..

Well it didn't work: I made the function `static` and declared it in the `main` method, still it didn't work. In the main method I made the function without an access specifier: still it didn't work.

Can't you declare a method in the `main` method?

Isn't there any way to declare a method inside the main method (other than making it public static outside the main method)?

```
public class TestArrays {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Step 1 & 2: declare/initialize array variables
    int[]  array1 = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };
    int[]  array2;

    // Step 3: display array1 with initial values
        System.out.print("array1 is ");
    printArray(array1);
    System.out.println();

    // Step 4: make array2 refer to array1
    array2 = array1;
    // modify array2
    array2[0] = 0;
    array2[2] = 2;
    array2[4] = 4;
    array2[6] = 6;
    // print array 1
    System.out.print("array1 is ");
    printArray(array1);
    System.out.println();


     static void printArray(int[] array) {
    System.out.print('<');
    for (int i:array ) {
      // print an element
      System.out.print(i);
      // print a comma delimiter if not the last element

      }
       System.out.print('>');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't (directly<sup>*</sup>) defined methods inside other methods in Java (and the `main` method is no special case here).

What you *want* to do is to put the method in the same *class* as `main`. If `main` needs to call it without creating an instance of the class, then it needs to be `static`, but it need not be `public`.

<sup>* You can declare a anonymous inner class with methods inside another method, however.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this in java. java uses classes, they encapsulate everything, even the main method - you put methods in classes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i think. it may work.

```
package practice;

class MyThreads extends Thread 

{
    MyThreads() 
    {
        System.out.print(" MyThreads");
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.print(" bar");
    }
    public void run(String s) 
    {
        System.out.println(" baz");
    }
}
public class TestThread 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    {
        Thread t = new MyThreads() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                System.out.println(" foo");
            }
        };
        t.start();
        System.out.println("out of run");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any features defined with in the method/block can't be accessed outside of it.

Because,As we know the scope of the that features ends at the end of the block/method.

So there is no external(Outside the Method) use of it.

for eg:

```
class Demo

{

       public static void main(String args[])

       {

       for(int i=0;i<10;i++) //for block

       {

           //.....

       }

       //outside of for loop

       System.out.println(i); // i can't be find symbol

       int sum()

       {

           int k=5;

       }

       //outside of sum()

       System.out.println(k); //won't get it.
   }

}
```

I think it is correct.otherwise correct me.